# MS-Access VBA: How to set field value back to old value if Form_Error event is triggered

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've had a request to return the value entered in a field by user to the previous value if it does not pass data validation criteria.

Where I can trap this in the `BeforeUpdate` event I am using a global variable to store the `.oldvalue` and then reassigning in the `AfterUpdate` event.

However data validation triggered by table structure exceptions (such as text in a number field) trigger the `Form_Error` event before the `BeforeUpdate` event and the `Form_Error` event does not relate to a specific field that I can store as an old value.

I could get around this by setting up the table as completely free text in all fields with nulls allowed, such that there would be no `Form_Error` event triggered and all validation handled in `BeforeUpdate`

Is this really the way I need to go about this? It seems odd to have to set up a nonsense table structure to handle errors but I'm struggling to come up with another method

Comment: Why handle the Form Error event at all? It seems to be doing what it should be, alerting to validation errors. These are probably not values you would consider reverting to or using for record level validation. They are the wrong data type/wrong at a more fundamental level than business rule validation. Processing should/cannot not proceed past this stage.

Comment: Yes but the default behaviour on this event is to leave the value the user has entered in the cell. For example if the value was previously 900 and the user enters '1k' the error will flag, but '1k' remains the value in the cell until the user manually changes it to something valid or escapes out. I want the cell value to revert to the original value (900) after displaying the error message

Comment: `Undo` then `Response = 0` ?

Comment: Thanks, was hoping it would be something simple. Easier than the storing the `.oldvalue` for the other fields as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm turning this comment into an answer. This is the gist of how to revert from the `Form_Error`.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Undo
    Response = 0
End Sub
```

You could do more like display a message on the screen saying what you did to you user then hide it on a timer event. Just something so their not sure why their data went away.

Comment: I already have the messages handled, was just trying very long winded versions of doing what undo can do for me. Thanks again, accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set yourglobal on the gotfocus event of the control. Then for the error event use

```
If err.number = 2107 then
yourfield = yourglobal
err.clear
end if
```